# g++ is missing when I use codeblocks

Tags: gcc, g++

I'm using codeblocks with fedora-16. When I try to build it starts the build but then says `"/bin/sh: g++ command not found".

If I select compile, it compiles OK.

So looking at this site they say that gcc uses g++ so I tried `"gcc -c this.c"` and that worked.

Does anyone have a clue as to what is going on?

Comment: `gcc` will invoke `g++` only if passed a C++ file. Try running `g++` directly to check if it exists.

Comment: I am building a C program and I created the codeblocks project telling it that. It is codeblocks that needs g++. But I did try g++ directly and it doesn't exist. I'm surprised codeblocks did not check to be sure all of the dependencies existed.

Answer (score 2):

In order to compile .c and .cpp files in Fedora you need to install a compiler.
To install the gcc and g++ compilers, you will need the build-essential package. This will also install GNU make.

build-essential contains a list of packages which are essential for building Ubuntu packages including gcc compiler, make and other required tools.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
$ gcc -v
$ make -v
```

Now, you should able to compile software using C / C++ compilers.

To install the manpages for c and c++ development, install the manpages-dev package.

If

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

doesn't work, try this:

```
 su -    
yum install make automake gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel
```

Comment: sudo wants a password that is not my user password nor is it the su password. So I tried apt-get under su and it says it does not exist. So I did these:

Comment: So I did these using yum under su. The update worked but upgrade said "no Packages marked for Update" and build-essential said "No package build-essential available".

Comment: You can try this:                                                    su -                                                                         yum install make automake gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel

Answer (score 0):

Codeblock invokes g++ to link the libraries.